# The 'Next badge' popup is appearing in the wrong place

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, responsive-design, popups

The 'Next badge' popup in the [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) expands page width on mobile:

> [image: Page width expansion]

Positioning the popup entirely in the original page area will prevent width expansion.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about that, that is how it has always been.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch has been doesn't mean right.